# unable to change symbol in nvd3 bubble chart

Tags: d3.js, symbols, nvd3.js, scatter-plot, bubble-chart

I am trying to have different plot symbol for each of the groups of points I have. The code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dm89/NYJpU/4/). I used this piece of code

```
shape: shapes[i]
```

But am unable to get different symbols. I am able to only get circles. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the below code before you call `d3.select('#chart svg')`

```
//We want to show shapes other than circles.
chart.scatter.onlyCircles(false);
```

Hope it helps.